Countable product of complete metric spaces is not necessarily complete?
Problem: Let $(X_n,d_n)$ be complete metric spaces for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and let $X=\prod_{n\in \mathbb N}X_n$, where each metric $d_n$ is such that the diameter $d_n(X_n)\leq 1$. Endow $X$ with the metric given by $$d((x_n), (y_n))=\max_{n\in \mathbb N}\frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{n}.$$ Is $(X,d)$ a complete metric space?
So far: I think the answer is no, since for proving the convergence of a Cauchy sequence we would have to choose a treshold index as the maximum of infinitely many treshold indices in the $(X_n,d_n)$'s, which is not a well-defined procedure. However, I can't really think of a concrete counter-example. I guess it's best to go easy (if it works), and choose $X_n=\mathbb R$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ and endow each copy of $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean metric. My first guess was to take a sequence in $X$ given by $$x_k^j=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if } k\leq j \\ 1 &\text{if } k>j \end{cases}$$ for each fixed $j$. I.e. each sequence consists of $j$ zeros followed by ones. I'm not completely convinced this works though.

Your "metric" isn't even well-defined. Let $X_n = \mathbb{R}$ and consider the points $x = (0){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $y = (n^2){n \in \mathbb{N}}$. What is $d(x, y)$?

Sorry, just updated with a more accurate description of the metrics on $X_n$ that I didn't see earlier.

One should probably write a supremum instead of a maximum

Our course notes give this motivation:  ''Since $d_j(x_j , y_j )/j\leq 1/j \to 0$, when
$j \to \infty$, we know that the maximum exists.''

You're right, since the diameters are bounded, the sequence goes to $0$ and hence has a maximum. That was my mistake.

The answer is actually yes, this space is complete. Try to identify the limit and then prove it converges.

Let $(X_m, d_m)$ be a sequence of complete metric spaces whose diameter is bounded by $1$. Endow the set $X = \prod\limits_m X_m$ with the following metric:
$$
d((x_m)_m, (y_m)_m) = \underset{m}{\operatorname{max}} \frac{1}{m} d_m(x_m, y_m)
$$
Then the resulting metric space $(X, d)$ is complete.
Let $((a_{n,m})_m)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$, meaning that
$$
d((a_{n_1,m})_m, (a_{n_2,m})_m) \overset{n_1, n_2 \to \infty}{\to} 0
$$
This just means that
$$
\underset{m}{\operatorname{max}} \frac{1}{m} d_m(a_{n_1,m}, a_{n_2,m}) \overset{n_1, n_2 \to \infty}{\to} 0
$$
Then, for each fixed $m$, it follows that
$$
d_m(a_{n_1,m}, a_{n_2,m}) \overset{n_1, n_2 \to \infty}{\to} 0
$$
This just means that the sequence $(a_{n,m})_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X_m$. Hence, it converges to a limit $b_m$. This means that for every $m$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N_{m, \varepsilon}$ such that for all $n \geq N_{m, \varepsilon}$, we have
$$
d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) < \varepsilon
$$
We will now show that
$$
(a_{n,m})_m \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} (b_m)_m
$$
in $X$.
Indeed, take any $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is some $M$ with $\frac{1}{M} \leq \varepsilon$. For each $1 \leq m \leq M$, let $N_{m, \varepsilon}$ be as above. Set $N_\varepsilon = \underset{1 \leq m \leq M}{\operatorname{max}} N_{m, \varepsilon}$. Now take any $n \geq N_\varepsilon$ and any $m$.
Now if $1 \leq m \leq M$, then we have $n \geq N_\varepsilon \geq N_{m, \varepsilon}$ and hence
$$
\frac{1}{m} d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) \leq d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) < \varepsilon
$$
On the other hand, if $M < m$, it follows that $\frac{1}{m} < \varepsilon$ and hence
$$
\frac{1}{m} d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) \leq \frac{1}{m} < \varepsilon
$$
We have shown that for all $m$,
$$
\frac{1}{m} d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) < \varepsilon
$$
This implies
$$
\underset{m}{\operatorname{max}} \frac{1}{m} d_m(a_{n,m}, b_m) < \varepsilon
$$
and hence
$$
d((a_{n,m})_m, (b_m)_m) < \varepsilon
$$
We have shown that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N_\varepsilon$ such that for all $n \geq N_\varepsilon$, we have
$$
d((a_{n,m})_m, (b_m)_m) < \varepsilon
$$
This means that
$$
(a_{n,m})_m \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} (b_m)_m
$$
in $X$.
We have shown that any Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges. This means that $(X, d)$ is complete.
